# Renci SSH SFTPrmote server public key request

Tags: ssh, sftp

I'm writing an application that uses the Renci libraries to upload and download files to an SFTP server.

So far the application works in terms of passing the public key portion of the clients private key to the server (the STP server has the clients public key).

The issue I'm having is in getting the Hosts public key. I need to retrieve this once I've connected  and ensure it matches the public key sent to us by the customer for the SFTP server.

I've looked through the Renci library and can't see how to do this. Is it possible?

I've also looked on this site and can't see an answer, hence this question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: See [Checking SFTP/SSH fingerprint in SSH.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31948661/850848).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You are welcome. Do not forget to upvote the question and the answer(s) that have helped you. Btw, I've just posted an up to date answer there. https://stackoverflow.com/q/31948661/850848#67380340

Comment: The problem I have now is converting the code examples on here to OpenEdge(Progress)!

Comment: You should edit your question accordingly, or post a new one. With relevant tags ([tag:openedge]).

Comment: Well, I've decided for now to use your WinSCP library rather than Renci. It's easy to configure to test the hosts public key...