# How to convert SSH host keys for validation?

Tags: c#, vb.net, rsa, ssh.net, ed25519

Using `SSH.NET`, I'm trying to get the same `ed25519` and `rsa` host keys from my SSH host (a Raspberry Pi in this case) that the Windows SSH client gets, so that I can compare them to what's in the `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\known_hosts` file.

The documentation demonstrates [this technique](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET#verify-host-identify), but `e.FingerPrint` contains a 16-element byte array. I wish to replicate the functionality of the in-built Win11 SSH client that retrieves and stores the host keys like so:

```
offsite ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAICuy9wsbY7fBFFoB6K0RU/BsISB3mL4PQ3311ta0S/cW
offsite ssh-rsa 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
```

I've tried looping through SSH.NET's `Client.ConnectionInfo.HostKeyAlgorithms` dictionary, but I'm not sure where to get the byte array that's required by an entry's value invocation:

```
Dim aData As Byte() = Nothing

For Each oAlgorithm In oClient.ConnectionInfo.HostKeyAlgorithms
  Dim oInstance = oAlgorithm.Value(aData)
End For
```

That code fails, as the `Func(Of Byte(), KeyHostAlgorithm)` invocation requires an actual array with elements. It also rejects an empty array (and any other array, for that matter). For example:

```
oAlgorithm.Value({})
```

> The requested length (4) is greater than the actual number of bytes read (0).Parameter name: length

```
oAlgorithm.Value({0, 1, 2})
```

> The requested length (4) is greater than the actual number of bytes read (3).Parameter name: length

```
oAlgorithm.Value({0, 1, 2, 3})
```

> Data longer than 2147483647 is not supported.

What gives here? What's that byte array parameter supposed to be and where does one get it?

I also tried this in the `Client.HostKeyReceived` event handler:

```
Dim sHostKey = Convert.ToBase64String(New SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(e.HostKey))
```

But that calculated Base64 string differs from the entry currently in my `known_hosts` file for that host (see above).

How do I retrieve the various keys from the SSH host, in a way that matches what's in `known_hosts` (`ed25519` and `rsa` in particular)?

**--EDIT--**

I've succeeded in discovering the byte array to be used in the function invocation:

```
oHandler = Sub(Sender As SshClient, e As HostKeyEventArgs)
             Dim aData As Byte()

             For Each oAlgorithm In Sender.ConnectionInfo.HostKeyAlgorithms
               Dim oInstance = oAlgorithm.Value(e.HostKey)

               If TypeOf oInstance.Key Is Ed25519Key Then
                 aData = DirectCast(oInstance.Key, Ed25519Key).PublicKey
                 Exit For
               End If
             Next
           End Sub
```

However, the computed Base64 of `aData` still doesn't match the output of the Win11 SSH client. Does anyone know how those values are arrived at?

**--EDIT--**

OK, I'm getting closer. I now have the Windows-supplied SSH client's value for `ed25519`. It's a straight Base64 encoding of the server's `HostKey`, prior to any hashing:

```
Dim sBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(e.HostKey)
' Returns AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAICuy9wsbY7fBFFoB6K0RU/BsISB3mL4PQ3311ta0S/cW
```

Now to tackle getting the same for the server's `rsa` key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is much simpler than I had anticipated: simply Base64-encode the host's `HostKey` byte array without hashing it (`SHA256` or `MD5`).

I was able to get the `rsa` key by requesting it at connection time:

```
sKeyType = "ssh-rsa"
oConnectionInfo = New PasswordConnectionInfo(Host.Name, Host.Username, Host.Password)
oConnectionInfo.HostKeyAlgorithms.Clear
oConnectionInfo.HostKeyAlgorithms.Add(sKeyType, Function(Data) New KeyHostAlgorithm(sKeyType, New RsaKey, Data))

Using oClient = New SshClient(oConnectionInfo)
  AddHandler oClient.HostKeyReceived, oHandler

  oClient.Connect
  oClient.CreateCommand("temp").Execute

  RemoveHandler oClient.HostKeyReceived, oHandler
End Using

oHandler = Sub(Sender As SshClient, e As HostKeyEventArgs)
             sBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(e.HostKey)

             e.CanTrust = Host.Base64 = sBase64
           End Sub
```

This works, and I can use it to compare the host's keys with the Windows-supplied SSH client's stored keys.